# Não consigo ativar o build trigger

Tags: jenkins

Estou com um pipeline no jenkins configurado que antes estava funcionando, mas teve um erro no jenkins e agora não consigo mais ativar a trigger. Já desconstruir o container docker do jenkins e fiz tudo do 0 e não consigo ativer a trigger de Poll SCM (GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling), quando faço alterações no repositório. Se executar manualmente ele funciona todo pipeline com sucesso.

Já baixei os plugins de Poll SCM, git plugin, Job Poll Action Plugin, Pipeline.

Já configurei o webhook no repositório, inclusive deletei e criei de novo e nada.
Tentei com token credenciais, tentei sem credenciais uma vez que o repositório é publico e nada.

Imagem no parte do jenkins no docker-compose:

```
jenkins:
        image: jenkinsci/blueocean
        container_name: jenkins
        restart: always
        user: root
        privileged: true
        ports:
                - 8080:8080
        volumes:
                - ./jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
                - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
                - /bin/docker:/bin/docker
```

O que mais me incomoda é que antes estava funcionando.

Comment: pode mostrar o código ou como está configurado o seu pipeline?